# How to use { useQuery } from react-query while iterating over an array of data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to integrate react-query into my React project.
What I have is a custom hook - `useBundles` which fetches data from a GraphQl endpoint as shown below -

```
function useBundles() {

  const { data, status, isSuccess } = useQuery(
    'SaleBundles',
    async () => await request(endpoint, gql`query {${saleQuery}}`),
  );

  return { data, status, isSuccess };
}
```

I use the return value in my component like this `const { data, status, isSuccess } = useBundles();` which works perfectly fine.

Now, what I want to do is, for each item in `data` I want to call another endpoint (a REST endpoint this time) and I have a seperate async function for that called `getData(data: Array)` which uses async-await to fetch data from my REST endpoint.

I could just call `getData` in `useBundles` passing to it `data` as an argument. But since `getData` is async it is required to use `await` with it (which I can't because I can't define a hook as async).

As an alternative, I tried not to use `getData` in `useBundles` but directly call the endpoint using axios like this -
`data.forEach((item) => useQuery("some-unique-key", axios.get(<endpoint>)))`

This gives me an error saying that `useQuery` cannot be used in a loop.

I'm kinda stuck at this point as how to proceed. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two ways to solve this:

1. [useQueries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries)

`useQueries` can be used with a fixed array, but also with a dynamic one, so:

```
useQueries(data.map(item => ...))
```

would work. It will give you an array of QueryResults back.

2. map and create a component

```
data.map(item => <Item {...item} />
```

then, you can call `useQuery` inside the `Item` component.

---

Both approaches will yield concurrent requests, the difference is mainly where you have access to the response data: With `useQueries`, you have access to all of them in your root component. With the second approach, each Item will only have access to its own data. So it just depends on your needs / use-case which version you prefer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, can you provide a more explicit example using useQueries for my use-case?

Comment: instead of using useQuery in a loop, useQueries.

Comment: `const results = useQueries(
    saleBundles.map((bundle) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ['SaleBundle', bundle.id],
        queryFn: async () => await fetchData(bundle, bundleTypes.sale),
      };
    }),
  );`

I'm doing this but on first load, results is an array of items and status is loading, so data is undefined

Comment: code looks right. status will be loading when the items are still fetching. As they come in one by one, those items in the array will go into success state.